# Create a datatable from a class and then pass to a stored procedure SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am wondering if anyone one can help me, I am trying to pass a data-table to a stored procedure using C# and SQL Server. The error message I am getting is

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with CustomerTermsTableType

Below is the type I created within SQL Server

Database type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CustomerTermsTableType AS TABLE 
( 
            DueDays int,
            DiscountPercent  DECIMAL (5, 2),
            DiscountDays int,
            CreditLimit DECIMAL (19, 4),
            ChargeInterest bit,
            IsStandardTerms bit,
            UseDiscounts bit,
            CompanyID  int,
            PaymentTimeFrame varchar(50) ,
            TrackingState int
);
GO
```

Then I created the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertTerms]
    @CustomerTermsTableType CustomerTermsTableType ReadONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Terms (ChargeInterest, CompanyID, DiscountDays, DueDays, DiscountPercent, IsStandardTerms, PaymentTimeFrame, TrackingState, UseDiscounts, CreditLimit)
        SELECT 
            ChargeInterest, CompanyID, DiscountDays, DueDays, DiscountPercent,
            IsStandardTerms, PaymentTimeFrame, TrackingState, UseDiscounts, CreditLimit
        FROM 
            @CustomerTermsTableType;
END
```

Creating and then filling the data table

```
public static DataTable CreateDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
    }

    foreach (T entity in list)
    {
        object[] values = new object[properties.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity);
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Running the stored procedure using c#.

```
 List<SqlParameter> TermParms = new List<SqlParameter>();
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
 parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
 parameter.TypeName = "dbo.CustomerTermsTableType";
 parameter.Value = CreateDataTable<termview>(newList);
 TermParms.Add(parameter);

 DbRawSqlQuery<dynamic> TermsID = _context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("sp_InsertTerms CustomerTermsTableType ", TermParms.ToArray());
```

Error

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with CustomerTermsTableType

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured out what was wrong. The problem was in with _context.Database.SqlQuery command, so I replaced it with below.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertTerms", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerTermsTableType", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = Terms;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue appears to be that your parameter name, @CustomerTermsTableType, is not being set to the SqlParameter object.  It is also not being assigned in the SQLQuery. It's also not clear why we need a parameter array when there is a single parameter.

Here is a simple example passing datatable to stored proc when using the dbcontext flavor as depicted in the question. This can be tweaked for a more complex scenario.

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@CustomerTermsTableType", SqlDbType.Structured);   
param.Value = CreateDataTable<termview>(newList);
param.TypeName = "dbo.CustomerTermsTableType";  

var TermsID = _context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("sp_InsertTerms @CustomerTermsTableType", param);
```

As a side note, I would suggest adding "SET NOCOUNT ON" to your stored procedure, before the query, as a performance boost.